# AutoHotKey remap page down to (ctrl + win + left)

Tags: windows-10, script, autohotkey

How do I remap <kbd>page down</kbd> to (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>) for Windows 10 desktop switch.

Same for <kbd>page up</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In AutoHotkey if you want to press the Page Up/Down keys and have it send the key combinations listed, your script should look something like this:

```
PgDn::Send ^#{Left}        ; ^ = Control and # = Windows Key
PgUp::Send ^#{Right}
```

Comment: PgDn::Send, ^#{Left}

Answer (score 0):

This person had the same issue that you were looking to resolve.  Microsoft has a solution that allows you to use multiple keys.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121760/remap-keyboard-combinations-not-just-single-registry-values

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

Comment: no not to multiple keys

Comment: So you want to map CONTROL + WINDOWS KEY + LEFT ARROW to be mapped to PAGE DOWN and CONTROL + WINDOWS KEY + RIGHT ARROW to be mapped to PAGE UP.  If this is correct then this application does this for you.  I just downloaded it and did it.  The application allows you to type the key for what you want the new combination to be and then you can also type the key that you want it mapped to.

Comment: I can only type 1 key "from" and 1 key "to", so how did you do it?

Comment: I see your point.  I'll modify my answer.  i found a solution for you though that should do.

Comment: Can't use the page up and I can't ever map a key to (ctrl + win + left)

Comment: I see your point.  Hard to find anything that really maps to both the special keys and the arrows.  While I DO see that the SharpKeys does show you the keys and when modifiers are pressed it doesn't do multiple.  And the Microsoft one falls short by not showing the arrows or windows key.  Very frustrating.  I wanted to see if I could find what the codes were for the combination you wanted, save the key mapping out with SharpKeys and then simply edit it by hand once the file was written.